# can't include("absolute_path")

Tags: php, include, absolute-path

I can't figure out why this won't work.

```
$docRoot = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT");
include_once($docRoot."/conn/connection.php");
include_once($docRoot."/auth/user.php");
```

It works locally through wamp, but it won't work on my live server.  I tried this:

```
if(!include_once($docRoot."/auth/user.php")){

   session_start();
   $debug = array();
   $debug["docRoot"] = $docRoot;
   $debug["inc_path"] = $docRoot."/auth/user.php";
   $debug["file_exists"] = file_exists($debug["inc_path"]);
   $_SESSION['DEBUG'] = $debug;

   // exit
   header("Location:debug.php"); 
   exit(); 
}
```

The debug page just echoes that array and it shows the correct absolute paths and indicates that the file does in fact exist.  So why didn't the include_once() work?  The server (a DV account on a MediaTemple server) has not been configured at all, so I wonder if there is an apache or php setting that is messing with me.

Ultimately, what I want here is a way to refer to a file in such a way that if I move the file, or include it in another file, nothing will break.  Any ideas?

Comment: What errors do you get? Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: The paths may be correct, but your PHP could be running with something like safe_mode turned on, which can rewrite include paths to restrict them to certain areas.

Comment: I'd be tempted to update your question with the debug output from the server. (i.e.: Show us a vardump of `$debug`.)

Comment: @Pekka - I get "Remote server or file not found" if I don't redirect to the debug page.

Comment: @Marc - ah ha..  it looks like my server is running with safe_mode on.  I'm not really comfortable with tinkering with such things so I didn't touch it..

Comment: @Pekka - Thanks for the prompt.  Turning on error reporting gave me what I needed.  It turns out this code works fine, but that an imported file that used the same technique were mistyped.  I had `include_once($docRoot."auth/user.php");` which was missing the slash before _auth/user.php_.  This broke the page, but I couldn't tell until error reporting was turned on.  But overall, it looks like this is going to be a good solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your debugging you might try `is_readable($docRoot."/conn/connection.php")`. The `file_exists` function will return true even if the file does not have readable permissions.

If you get an error code we might be able to provide more info as to what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on error reporting dummy.  It turns out one of the includes on another file was breaking this page and I wasn't able to trace that out until I turned on error reporting.

Incidentally, the problematic include was missing a leading slash in the filepath ( include("dir/file.ext"); ) which works on my local wamp setup and breaks on the linux server.